# Offline Japanese to English Translator with Command Line Support

Tags: windows, offline, command-line, translation

I am looking for a program I can use (either open-source, or free/gratis) to translate a bunch of text files from Japanese to English.

There seems to be very little support for this from the professional translation tools. I would really like a way to use Atlas to translate all the files via command Line usage (if anyone knows how to do translations via command-line With Atlas Please let me know).

I would like to keep it as minimalistic as possible, in terms of running it. If possible, I would like to be able to call it from a command-line `program.exe "C:\file.txt" "C:\file-translated.txt"` (something along those lines).

Thanks in advance for any suggestions =)